# How would one deal with a cyclically recursive relation?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

I get stuck when such a problem arises:

Suppose I want to find `foo(n)`. I know a formula for `foo(n)`, but it includes both `foo(n-1)` and `foo(n+1)` in it's calculation.

If I tried to solve these with the a naive recursive function then these two function calls would again call the parent function through them. This would result in an infinite loop! e.g. Trying to solve `foo(n)` would involve calling `foo(n+1)` which would call back to `foo(n)`, and so on.

Is there a general technique to address this particular type of problem, without relying on any assumptions about the exact calculation of `foo(n)` from `foo(n-1)` and `foo(n+1)`?

**EDIT:**

In my example, I know `foo(n) = 0` and `foo(n-1) = 1` for a particular `n`, and I want to calculate all the values between `foo(n-2)` and `0`.

Comment: That's not a well-defined problem, neither mathematically nor computationally. *What* are you trying to compute?

Comment: Are there any upper limit for foo to stop?

Comment: by putting `if(n < low || n > high) return;`

Comment: _'How are such problems addressed in programming?'_ E.g. specifying s.th. like a maximum recursion depth.

Comment: @Luu Vinh Phuc: It would stop at foo(0)?

Comment: Is there a specific recursion formula you use? Perhaps some math tricks could get you `foo(n)` as a function of `foo(n-1)` and `foo(n-2)` ultimately having a lower bound only ...

Comment: @delnan This is not generally true; if `f(n) = f(n+1) - f(n-1)`, then that gives you `f(n+1) = f(n) + f(n-1)`.

Comment: @G.Bach Still lacks a base case. You can spin it into a "find a function f that satisfies `f`" style exercise, but that's not what's done here. I was also (come to think of it, primarily) referring to the fact that *nothing else* was specified about foo(n).

Comment: @delnan I think it's reasonable to assume that there are base cases available. Even if they aren't, you can parametrize the recursion with variable base cases.

Comment: @G.Bach I see two options: Either there are base cases (in both directions), or OP has misunderstood the problem and a *correct* definition of foo(n) isn't actually of the form described in the question. In the first case, why is OP so confused? I consider the second more likely, hence my request for more details.

Comment: @delnan Base cases, even in both directions, are useless since you can only move one step at a time. You'd need to have the whole sequence as base case, but then the recursion is useless. I expect that you can solve the definition of f(n) for f(n+1), don't see how this could work any other way.

Comment: @G.Bach Yes, that's a good point about base cases. So we're on the same page now? There's way too little information in the question to answer it.

Comment: @delnan There is too little information to answer the question, but there's also too little information to say that the problem can't be well-defined the way user2732146 described it.

Comment: @G.Bach I did not say the problem OP is facing is not well-defined (if it read like that, my apologize, taking that back). I said what's written in the question is not a well-defined problem.

Comment: There is a case: F(n) = 0 and F(n-1) = 1. Does this help?

Comment: @delnan I may have misread your first comment; I took it to mean "you can't solve a recursion like that", which was reading a bit much into it.

Comment: @user2732146 If you also have the recursion itself, it will. I expect this to come out to Fibonacci, right now.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why this question is downvoted or why people are talking about needing both bounds and having to step all the way up then down again. This seems to be a case of people not knowing the answer to a question and so drawing incorrect assumptions

Comment: @delnan What information is missing? The OP doesn't want a full explanation of how to solve his entire problem, he wants to know how to avoid loops of recursion when the recursive function involves terms both higher and lower than itself. This is a well-defined question with a well-defined answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the solution to this is very simple. If you have a relation something like:

```
f(n) = f(n+1) - f(n-1)
```

All you have to do is subtract positive `k` from each of the inner terms such that no term is a function of anything higher than `n`. For example, in this case `k` would be `1`:

```
f(n-1) = f(n) - f(n-2)
```

Rearrangement then gets:

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)
```

Which you might recognise as the fibonacci sequence. That's just an example, it doesn't matter what the relation between `f(n)`, `f(n+1)` and `f(n-1)` is as long as it's a function you can reverse, you can always shift the function arguments to get it into a function of `f(n)`, `f(n-1)` and `f(n-2)`. Another example:

```
f(n) = f(n+1) / f(n-1)
f(n-1) = f(n) / f(n-2)
f(n) = f(n-1) * f(n-2)
```

In more general terms, if you have:

```
f(n) = H[f(n+1), f(n-1)]
```

Then you can transform that to:

```
f(n) = H-1[f(n-1), f(n-2)]
```

Where H is a function, and H<sup>-1</sup> is its inverse.

This assumes you have two values at the lower bound and want to step upwards. (e.g. `f(0) = 1, f(1) = 1`). If you have upper bounds and want to step down, then you'd add `k` instead of subtract

Comment: user2732146 didn't specify whether f(n) is the sum, product, difference, or something else of f(n+1) and f(n-1). While I expect this to be what he'll end up saying, we don't know that right now.

Comment: @G.Bach But it doesn't matter. Whatever the relation is you can do the same thing. This was just an example. If it was `f(n)=f(n+1)f(n-1)`, again you could shift that to `f(n-1) = f(n)f(n-2)` giving `f(n) = f(n-1)/f(n-2)`